# Node 6 debugger windows - Error trying to copy the OSX app icon to customize electron-prebuilt

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, windows-10, npm-install

I just updated to Node v6 (installed latest win executable from their website), and apparently I can't see to use the "debugger" anymore in my projects

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Dev\myNodeProject\debugger'

I tried to install this package but then I run into errors

> npm install debugger --save

```
electron-prebuilt@1.0.2 postinstall C:\Dev\myNodeProject\node_modules\electron-prebuilt
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v1.0.2-win32-x64.zip
[============================================>] 100.0% of 49.69 MB (407.27 kB/s)

> debugger@0.35.0 postinstall C:\Dev\myNodeProject\node_modules\debugger
> node bin/postinstall.js

Error trying to copy the OSX app icon to customize electron-prebuilt
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "debugger" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! debugger@0.35.0 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the debugger@0.35.0 postinstall script 'node bin/postinstall.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the debugger package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node bin/postinstall.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs debugger
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls debugger
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

So is this really a bug that I should report, or am I missing something trivial ? The error mentions OSX but obviously I'm not running that...

Comment: Same is the case for node `7.8.0`, npm `4.2.0` on Fedora-21.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with node `v7.8.0` and npm '4.2.0' on Fedora-21.

Investigated around an hour to get the clue to resolving the issue but didn't help much.

However, I come across a module `node-inspect` which perfectly works for me and serves the purpose I'm looking for.

```
npm install node-inspect
```

And then use it like

```
node inspect my-script.js
```

For more detail you can refer [npm official sites](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)